# OpenXML xml snippet for a bulleted list

Tags: openxml, phpword

I am using PHPWord to ger
nerate word elements. I want to insert a bulleted list using setValue in my template.

I tried inserting this snippet

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
      <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
      <w:numId w:val="1"/>
    </w:numPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>One</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

But somehow I am missing the style. where do I need to insert the style and what style?

I worked based on that page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ee922775%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: What do you mean when you say "missing the style"? The `<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>` element provides the link to the style. What actual behavior are you observing? (like error message or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<w:pStyle>` element takes the style ID as its `w:val` attribute. So in this case, the 'List Paragraph' style. `List Paragraph` does not have a bullet. If you want a bullet you'll need to use `List Bullet` instead.

Note that this will only actually work if the style in question is explicitly defined in the `/word/styles.xml` part. The `List Bullet` style is a so-called 'built-in' style, and is not written by Word into the styles.xml part until it is used for the first time.

So it's possible you may need to add it yourself. The Word behavior when a paragraph is assigned an undefined style is simply to use the default paragraph style, probably `Normal`.

Comment: Where can I find the built-in styles? I can not find the ListBullet sytel

Comment: There is a pretty good list here, although I believe the latest versions have a few more: http://www.thedoctools.com/downloads/DocTools_List_Of_Built-in_Style_English_Danish_German_French.pdf